# plusDomains.activities.list returns empty or incomplete list of Activities

Tags: google-plus

In our web-application (running in AppEngine) we are using Google Plus Domains API and user delegation/impersonation (with service account). We basically loop over all users in the domain in order to get all published activities. This works quite well for majority of users. However we have found at least one user whose activities are not returned correctly.

In the app code (with impersonation) the `plusDomains.activities.list` returns only 3 non-public activities for this user though there is certainly more Activities which are visible fine through plus.google.com pages in various communities.

Is there some setting/settings combination in this particular user's G+ profile that prevents the Plus Domains API to read the posts. I have already tried to change e.g. the target audience age in another test profile in order to reproduce the issue, but failed so far. Or is there something else to check or perhaps even a bug in the API? This is quite critical problem.

Furthermore when trying the API here
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plusDomains/v1/plusDomains.activities.list
It returns completely empty list of activities for this user. For other users in the same domain it works fine.

EDIT: In addition now we have found another case. It seems that impersonated `plusDomains.activities.list` call for these users returns only "Domain" and "Shared privately" scoped Activities. All Activities posted to Communities seems to be missing, which is very strange!?

Comment: My guess is that Google has some bad caches for the specific user's activities. Not sure there is much you can do other than hope the caches clear or Google finds a bug and fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

This is now at least partially solwed. If the Google+ user has this setting:
**"Show your Google+ communities posts on your profile."** OFF the Plus Domains API (even if impersonated) can not read the community posts (activities). So every user has to enable this by themselves. It is under https://plus.google.com/settings Profile section.